# Django REST Framework: Exclude one queryset from another with combined filters

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filters

I have the following method which return objects for `is_active=True` and for particular user.

```
def filter_active_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(active_states__is_active=True,
                           active_states__user_id=value)
```

I would like to build a method which will return a queryset with all the objects which are not included in the above method. So I created the following method using `exclude`:

```
def filter_inactive_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.exclude(active_states__is_active=True,
                            active_states__user_id=value)
```

I also tried the following implementation using `~Q`:

```
def filter_inactive_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(~Q(active_states__is_active=True,
                              active_states__user_id=value))
```

But, I don't get the correct results. 
For example in a test case, I have created some data, consisted of 3 objects. Using the method `filter_active_user` I'm getting 1 object and I expect to get the other 2 using the `filter_inactive_user` method, but I'm getting also 1. To be more specific below presented my test data:

```
record_1.set_active_states_for_users([self.user1.uuid], True)
record_2.set_active_states_for_users([self.user1.uuid], False)
record_2.set_active_states_for_users([self.user2.uuid], True)
record_3.set_active_states_for_users([self.user2.uuid], False)
```

When I'm using the the `filter_active_user` for `user=user2` I'm getting the `record_2`.
When I'm using the `filter_inactive_user` for `user=user2` I'm getting only the `record_1` and not the `record_3`.
Can you help me to build the properly way to combine two filters in a queryset?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, isn't the only difference from the first snippet you need to make `__is_active=False`?

Comment: I have used the same filters in order to use the `exclude` keyword in the first attempt and `~Q` in the second attempt.

Comment: You may need to further define "I dont get the correct results" (what results do you get?).. There maybe a subtle difference in the query created between excluding and just setting it to false in the filter

Comment: There doesn't seem be a relevant difference there. Maybe the queryset you get in the method has been already changed?

Comment: @Sayse you are right, just added more information about the test data which I used and what I expected to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
def filter_inactive_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    qs_active = queryset.filter(active_states__is_active=True, active_states__user_id=value)
    qs_inactive = queryset.exclude(pk__in=qs_active.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

**Solution 2:**

```
def filter_inactive_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    qs_inactive = queryset.exclude(active_states__is_active=True).exclude(active_states__user_id=value)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. The first solution works for me. The second solution doesn't work for me.